# Join two tables not having a common ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  table Cycle:

```
CycleID   CycleName

1         2017   
2         2018
3         2019
```

And  table Entity

```
EntityID  Entity   Description

1         Entity1
2         Entity2
3         Entity3
```

I need to loop to generate a third table that store the following:

```
EntityID EntityDescription CycleID CycleName

1        Entity1           1       2017   
2        Entity2           1       2018
3        Entity3           1       2019
1        Entity1           1       2017   
2        Entity2           1       2018
3        Entity3           1       2019
1        Entity1           1       2017   
2        Entity2           1       2018
3        Entity3           1       2019
```

Comment: Do you want all the `CycleID`s as 1 in the third table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `NewTable`;

CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
`EntityID` int NOT NULL ,
`EntityDescription` varchar(255) NULL,
`CycleID` int NOT NULL ,
`CycleName` varchar(255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO `NewTable`
(EntityID, EntityDescription, CycleID, CycleName)
SELECT * FROM Cycle, entity
```

It works on my database. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to join every row of table Cycle to every row of table Entity. You need a cartesian join:

```
select e.entity_id,
    e.entity_description,
    c.cycle_id,
    c.cycle_name
from entity e
cross join cycle c
```

Comment: Better write `entity e CROSS JOIN
    cycle c` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
 SELECT ... FROM entity,cycle
```

will do (in mssql and oracle at least).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  Entity.EntityID,Entity.EntityDescription , Cycle.CycleID, Cycle.CycleName

FROM Entity CROSS JOIN Cycle;
```

In this sql query we are joining 2 tables using inner join and condition of join is CycleID and EntityID should match.

Comment: There is no such thing as `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Thanks for telling Edited.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is still not valid SQL, no `join` without `on` (besides the correct answer `CROSS JOIN`)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution